# type Module is not assignable to type LoginModule

Tags: typescript

Assuming this code:

```
class Module{
    contructor(){
        // some logic here
    }
}

class LoginModule extends Module{
    start(){}

}

class Server{
    modules: Module[];
    constructor(modules?: Array<{new():Module}>){
        for(var moduleConstructor of modules){
            var module = new moduleConstructor();
            this.modules.push(module);
        }
    }
} 

var server = new Server([LoginModule]);
var loginModule:LoginModule = server.modules[0];
```

why I'm getting error:

> Type 'Module' is not assignable to type 'LoginModule'. Property 'start' is missing in type 'Module'.

I need to have array of object of classes extended from `Module` and then I would like to typescript to recognize object type.

I can change

```
var loginModule:LoginModule = server.modules[0];
```

to

```
var loginModule:Module = server.modules[0];
```

but then I will loose intellisense hints in my IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The defintion of property `modules` is

```
class Server{
    modules: Module[]; // type is not LoginModule, just Module
    ...
```

so, it is for sure not of a LoginModule. But, in case, we know that the instance is LoginModule, we can use assignment with **assert** *(the `as` statement)*:

```
//var loginModule:LoginModule = server.modules[0];
var loginModule = server.modules[0] as LoginModule;
```

And now, the loginModule variable is treated as the `LoginModule` instance...

Comment: Never heard about `as` operator before. Thanx, this is exactly what I need.

Comment: What if `server.modules[0]` isn't a `LoginModule` - there is nothing to enforce that it will be. If you must always have a `LoginModule` then you should ungeneralise your code and require a `LoginModule` in the `Server` constructor.

Comment: The as operator is **assert** ... it means, that we say "I as developer know more then you, Typescript. I assert you, that behind is really type I want" ... so if this is not true, in run-time you can really experience scenarios like method is undefined... hope it helps a bit ... and ultimate guide **https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html**

Comment: @Sohnee, there can be (and in my project actually are) hundreds different modules. All I want is to ensure that all those modules extended from basic class which made them actually a module in terms of my application.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Server` requires a `LoginModule`, make the requirement explicit by requiring a `LoginModule`:

```
class Module{
    contructor(){
        // some logic here
    }
}

class LoginModule extends Module{
    start(){}

}

class Server{
    modules: Module[];
    constructor(public loginModule: LoginModule, modules?: Array<{new():Module}>){
        for(var moduleConstructor of modules){
            var module = new moduleConstructor();
            this.modules.push(module);
        }
    }
} 

var server = new Server(new LoginModule, [LoginModule]);
var loginModule:LoginModule = server.loginModule;
```

The type system will now save you as a consumer as well as a provider, because if you try to pass some other kind of `Module` it will warn you. You also get back the expected type.

You can still provide different `LoginModule` types, as long as they are structurally identical.

I suspect that you don't want every module to be swappable, but instead want certain kinds of module to be swappable - so allow either one or more of each type in your constructor (I'm imagining that you are aiming from something akin to Express middleware, where you may allow users to specify a number of handlers for certain kinds of event).

Comment: This is not a case for me. In my example I know that first element of modules arrays is an object of `LoginModule`. But in real situation it will be just array of maybe 10 or mode objects in random order and all I will know is that all of them extended from one base class.

Comment: Even more reason not to assert that it is a `LoginModule`. Do you need to call different methods for each one depending on what it is? Or can you enforce an interface on them all, for example by ensuring they all have a `handle` method?